# How is the Correct Validation?

Tags: android

**Correct me if my Validation is wrong**

```
    if (sqlName.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        sqlName.setError("Name is required!");
    } else if (sqlAge.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        sqlAge.setError("Age is required!");
    }else if(statusbutton.getText().toString().length() == 0){
        statusbutton.setError("Please Select Status before you Proceed");
    }else if (sqlcycle.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        sqlcycle.setError("Cycle Lenght is required!");
    }else if (sqlperiod.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        sqlperiod.setError("Period is required!");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    didItWork = false;
    String error = e.toString();
    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("FACK");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(error);
    d.setContentView(tv);
    d.show();
} finally {
    if (didItWork) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "USER Information has been Save", 1000).show();
    } 
    else {
        Intent main = new Intent(this, CalendarMain.class);
        startActivity(main);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Problem: I want to vaidate first the before it move to the next activity
but still even though the edittext is empty it still go to next activity.

Comment: You should improve your coding standard. This is not at all looking good

Comment: Which default value is of `didItWork`? It looks like it is always `false`.

Comment: what do u mean by always false? i don't get it?
im beginner and still learning

Comment: No where in your code are you saying `didItWork = true1` so we have to assume you never set it to true, therefore it is always false and the else statement is always going to get called.

Furthermore, if `didItWork` is false (which i assume you want that to mean the validation was not successful?) it will launch the Calendar Main activity, which to me does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your didItWork=false;

and insert else code also like below

```
else if (sqlperiod.getText().toString().length() == 0) { 
    sqlperiod.setError("Period is required!"); 
} 
else
{
     didItWork=true;
}
```

and in your finally block

```
 finally { 
 if (didItWork) { 
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "USER Information has been Save", 1000).show();
    Intent main = new Intent(this, CalendarMain.class);
    startActivity(main);
    finish();
}  
else { 
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Error", 1000).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First of all use this

```
sqlName.getText().toString().trim().length()
```

in place of

```
sqlName.getText().toString().length()
```

this will not move to next screen if you start with spaces

I have no idea where the your code is going null pointer exception but i just tried to implement it and i am not getting such exceptions. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4, edt5;
    Button btn;
    boolean didItWork = true;
    Dialog d;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        edt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt3);
        edt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt4);

        edt5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt5);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (edt1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        // sqlName.setError("Name is required!");
                    } else if (edt2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        // sqlAge.setError("Age is required!");
                    } else if (edt3.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        // statusbutton.setError("Please Select Status before you Proceed");
                    } else if (edt4.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        // sqlcycle.setError("Cycle Lenght is required!");
                    } else if (edt5.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        // sqlperiod.setError("Period is required!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    didItWork = false;
                    String error = e.toString();
                    d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                    d.setTitle("FACK");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    tv.setText(error);
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "USER Informatisdefsdfon has been Save", 1000)
                            .show();
                } finally {
                    if (didItWork) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "USER Information has been Save", 1000).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                CalendarMain.class);
                        startActivity(main);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And layout goes like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
            <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edt3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
                <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edt4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

                    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edt5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
                        <Button
       android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tnx,,.. i get it but another problem occur,..
the new problem is NullPointerException? can you pinpoint the problem?

Comment: do you know what pinpoints the problem? *THE STACKTRACE*, it literally tells you what line it encountered `null` on.